# Cannot position text over image in a css grid system

Tags: html, css, background-image

What I am trying to do is position text over these images. I want them to be in the bottom left corner but whatever I try, nothing seems to get them to work. I am able to change their size and color and padding but I am not able to place them where I want in the div. Any suggestion helps and I appreciate it all! Thankyou

HTML:

```
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="f f1">
        <h3>My Beautiful Dark Fantasy</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="f f2">
            <h3>My Beautiful Dark Fantasy</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="f f3">
        <h3>My Beautiful Dark Fantasy</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="f f4">
        <h3>My Beautiful Dark Fantasy</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="f f5">
        <h3>My Beautiful Dark Fantasy</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 6rem;
min-height: 100%;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}


.nav {
background: #ddd;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0;
}

.nav a {
padding: 10px;
}

.grid { 
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 350px;
margin: 30px 150px 30px 150px;
position: relative;
}

.f {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: grey;
}

.f h3{
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
}

.f1 {
grid-column: 1/3;
grid-row: 1/3;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
url("/images/album/tyler.jpg");
}

.f2 {
grid-column: 3/4;
grid-row: 1/2;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
url("/images/album/dope.jpg");

}

.f3 {
grid-column: 3/4;
grid-row: 2/4;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
url("/images/album/kanye.jpg");

}

.f4 {
grid-column: 1/2;
grid-row: 3/4;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
url("/images/album/selfie.jpg");

}

.f5 {
grid-column: 2/3;
grid-row: 3/4;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 
url("/images/album/fantasy.jpg");

}


.footer {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: #efefef;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is position text over these images.

In given example, try to change this:

```
.f h3{
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
}
```

to this:

```
.f h3{
color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

Adding absolute positioning inside an .f which is positioned relative should work.

Answer (score 3):

a good solution is to stack the text grid and the image grid on top of each other by setting the `grid-column` and `grid-rows` to same for both. then just use `z-index` to bring thee text forward.

You can easily move the text anywhere now. It is responsive as well. Very powerful method we are able to utilize cause of `css grid`.  You can get really creative with this method. `Multi-stacking` been working on making a single page webpage where you just get to various parts of pages by just bring forward the page you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: how about an example

Answer (score 1):

having the following html

```
  <div class="item image-text-center">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">Hello, World</div>
  </div>
```

this will center the text

```
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


.item.image-text-center .text{
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  display: grid;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

[image]